# How can I save / generated multiple single graphs from faceted graphs at once?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet

I have a dataset of >100 different samples. Samples are from different genotypes (e.g. X, Y, Z) and 4 different time points (T0,1,2,3) with 3 biological replicates (R1,2,3). I'm measuring values for 50 different genes (in rows; A,B..)

```
longdata <- structure(list(Gene = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Genotype = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("X", "Y", "Z"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("T0", 
    "T1", "T2", "T3"), class = "factor"), Ave = c(1.32606106633333, 
    1.499956424, 1.118528738, 1.025082136, 0.424537206666667, 
    0.723243112666667, 0.335509156333333, 0.328275209, 0.788329993666667, 
    1.125292329, 2.357924224, 0.678921448, 0.222768019, 0.293117217, 
    0.548228048, 0.841192647333333, 3.144197864, 0.576764958333333, 
    1.32037215366667, 1.15039119233333, 1.03539976366667, 1.00032109266667, 
    0.740699933666667, 0.687992671666667), SE = c(0.119785209010494, 
    0.168580466330281, 0.264739468221289, 0.124588107424543, 
    0.194995686650518, 0.0392007703821249, 0.06203362889702, 
    0.0482287534807508, 0.396968455138007, 0.0903480171168777, 
    0.717823561374135, 0.164024037188693, 0.0078580995264886, 
    0.0980939303386436, 0.233081861930954, 0.0870744069976396, 
    0.324195222544884, 0.434640930315622, 0.0658409437053185, 
    0.135850334794207, 0.175517934316736, 0.123213160632528, 
    0.133598346586129, 0.203707785326976)), .Names = c("Gene", 
"Genotype", "Time", "Ave", "SE"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

How can I modify this syntax to generate each graph separately and save them as JPG/PNG files?

```
longdata %>% ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = Ave, fill = Genotype)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Ave - SE, ymax = Ave + SE), width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(0.9)) + facet_wrap(~ Gene)
```

Comment: I think you posted the wrong data set. There is no `Time` in the data set you posted.

Comment: @ hpesoj626  Sorry,  I've named samples (in columns) with time points. i.e. here  X_T0_R1 ; X: genotype, T: time point, R: Replicate. I've used ; (longdata <- dataset %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Gene) %>% 
  separate(key, c("Genotype", "Time", "Replicate")))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `ggplot` and `ggsave` within a loop.

```
lapply(sort(unique(longdata$Gene)), function(i){
  ggplot(longdata[longdata$Gene == i, ], aes(x = Time, y = Ave, fill = Genotype)) + geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Ave - SE, ymax = Ave + SE), width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(0.9))
  ggsave(filename = paste0(i, ".png"))
})
```

This loop gets the unique elements of `Gene`, sorts them, create a plot, then save the result.